# How to get a parameter from JAVA httpSession and use/set it on a dao class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to use a servlet to validate login/password. That's fine already.

I have a method in a DAO class that returns a resultSet list of values through a prepareStatement.

I'm using a query that brings this filtered result with a where clause (by user's name).

The problem is: how can I get the servlet parameter (name of the user who logged in) and set it  on the prepareStatement ?

The code follows:

```
public class DaoPojoJoin extends Dao {

public List<PojoJoin> listUserDegrees() {
    List<PojoJoin> dg = new ArrayList<PojoJoin>();
    if (openConnection()) {
        try {
            st = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT USER, MATTER, DEGREE FROM DEGREES x "
                    + "right outer join USERS y on x.idUser=y.idUser "
                    + "right outer join MATTER z on idMatter=z.idMatter "
                    + "where x.iduser=?"); // filter result by user's name

            // How can I have something like this:
            // st.setString(1,usr.request.getParameter("user"));

            // or this:
            // st.setString(1,.getAttribute(user));

            rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                PojoJoin pj = new PojoJoin();
                rs.getString("USER"); 
                rs.getString("MATTER");
                rs.getDouble("DEGREE");
                pj.setUsuario(rs.getString("USER"));
                pj.setDisciplina(rs.getString("MATTER"));
                pj.setNota(rs.getDouble("DEGREE"));
                nota.add(pj);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            err = ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
    return dg;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for it as method argument. The DAO should not care about the context it is sitting in and is supposed to be reuseable everywhere else (e.g. a plain vanilla Java Application which doesn't use servlets).

Thus so

```
public List<PojoJoin> listUserDegrees(String username) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
public List<PojoJoin> listUserDegrees(Long userId) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
public List<PojoJoin> listUserDegrees(User user) {
    // ...
}
```

Finally just let the caller (the servlet) pass it in.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your DB resource handling doesn't seem to be threadsafe. I'd work on that to avoid serious problems whenever your webapp starts to be used by multiple users.

Comment: Hey man, I've just read one of your articles in your http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

Comment: I feel proud receiving your answer. I'll try to understand your wisely  explanation and do it here. About the threadsafe issue don't mind, cuz this webapp is just an mba exercise. But I'll keep that in mind, too.